# cv_bridge install error on rpi rosindigo

Tags: wheezy, raspberrypi, cv-bridge, rasbperrypi, vision-opencv

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello!

sorry for my bad english.

im trying to get this tutorial: [ANTDROID](https://github.com/antdroid-hexapod/antdroid/wiki/Installation)
to work on my raspberry pi.

i followed the instructiones and it crashes istalling cv_bridge

also this tutorial: [ROS on Raspberry Pi](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSberryPi/Installing%20ROS%20Indigo%20on%20Raspberry%20Pi)

and this tutorial: [ROS on Debian](http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Debian)

crashes everytime when i paste "vision_opencv" in "rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall"

now im working on it about 3 weeks at any free minute i have. imgoing crazy.

i tied all commands and instructions abaud openCV, CV_Bridge and so on from the internet i found

it installs 73 packages from 101 packages and then crashes...

libconsole-bridge-dev and liblz4-dev are installed

i have tried a original rpi wheezy image and a image with preinstalled basic ros_comm

with the preinstalled ros image i can do:
rosinstall_generator ros_comm --rosdistro indigo --deps --wet-only --exclude roslisp --tar > indigo-ros_comm-wet.rosinstall

and 48 from 48 operacion work perfectly

i tried tru ssh connection on windows / ubundtu and also with mouse and keyboard direct on the rpi

please, please give me a little step by step instruction to get this error with cv_bridge to work

here is the error text i get:

Processing catkin package: 'cv_bridge'
==> Building with env: '/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh'
Makefile exists, skipping explicit cmake invocation...
==> make cmake_check_build_system in '/home/pi/ros_from_sources/build_isolated/cv_bridge'
==> make -j4 -l4 in '/home/pi/ros_from_sources/build_isolated/cv_bridge'
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] [  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] [  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/cv_bridge.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:36:0:
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:26:3: warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:329:72: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:331:78: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:333:75: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:335:75: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:411:65: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:413:71: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:415:68: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:417:68: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In function 'cv::Mat cv_bridge::matFromImage(const Image&)':
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:265:23: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:265:55: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:266:23: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:266:55: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In member function 'void cv_bridge::CvImage::toImageMsg(sensor_msgs::Image&) const':
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:360:44: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:360:76: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In function 'cv_bridge::CvImageConstPtr cv_bridge::toCvShare(const Image&, const boost::shared_ptr&, const string&)':
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:410:23: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:410:55: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/cv_bridge.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/cv_bridge.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:643: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
<== Failed to process package 'cv_bridge':
Command '['/opt/ros/indigo/env.sh', 'make', '-j4', '-l4']' returned non-zero exit status 2

Reproduce this error by running:
==> cd /home/pi/ros_from_sources/build_isolated/cv_bridge && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4

Command failed, exiting.

pi@raspberrypi ~/ros_from_sources $  cd /home/pi/ros_from_sources/build_isolated/cv_bridge && /opt/ros/indigo/env.sh make -j4 -l4
[ 25%] [ 25%] [ 25%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 25%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 25%] [ 25%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 25%] [ 25%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 25%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 25%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/cv_bridge.cpp.o
In file included from /home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:36:0:
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:26:3: warning: scoped enums only available with -std=c++0x or -std=gnu++0x [enabled by default]
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:329:72: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:331:78: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:333:75: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:335:75: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:328:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversible> struct boost::endian::detail::value_converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:411:65: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:413:71: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:415:68: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:417:68: error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 3)
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/boost/endian/conversion.hpp:410:13: error: provided for 'template<boost::endian::order From, boost::endian::order To, class EndianReversibleInplace> struct boost::endian::detail::converter'
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In function 'cv::Mat cv_bridge::matFromImage(const Image&)':
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:265:23: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:265:55: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:266:23: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:266:55: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In member function 'void cv_bridge::CvImage::toImageMsg(sensor_msgs::Image&) const':
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:360:44: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:360:76: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp: In function 'cv_bridge::CvImageConstPtr cv_bridge::toCvShare(const Image&, const boost::shared_ptr&, const string&)':
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:410:23: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
/home/pi/ros_from_sources/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp:410:55: error: 'boost::endian::order' is not a class or namespace
src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/build.make:54: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/cv_bridge.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/cv_bridge.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:643: recipe for target 'src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/cv_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:123: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224904/cv_bridge-install-error-on-rpi-rosindigo/) by [g.sart](https://answers.ros.org/users/25706/g.sart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-01-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Wheezy has boost libraries 1.49, endian library is from version 1.58.

**Working solution**

use only if you are interfacing computers with little endian operating systems.

in file ~/ros_catkin_ws/src/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/src/cv_bridge.cpp make follow changes:

comment:

```
//#include "boost/endian/conversion.hpp"
```

comment:

```
//if ((boost::endian::order::native == boost::endian::order::big && source.is_bigendian) ||
//    (boost::endian::order::native == boost::endian::order::little && !source.is_bigendian) ||
//    byte_depth == 1)
    return mat;
```

change:

```
ros_image.is_bigendian = 0;//(boost::endian::order::native == boost::endian::order::big);
```

partially comment and change:

```
if ((!encoding.empty() && source.encoding != encoding))// || (source.is_bigendian &&
    //(boost::endian::order::native != boost::endian::order::big)))
return toCvCopy(source, encoding);
```

---

Originally posted by [Mikisoft](https://answers.ros.org/users/25726/mikisoft/) with karma: 16 on 2016-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0